# GCP BigQuery Quota: Exactly when will the quota be restricted?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, quota, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to restrict `Query usage/day/user` quota on GCP, and I have a question about this. Exactly when will the quota be limited?

Will the restriction be applied from the first query that exceeds the set quota, or will the restriction be applied before the query, which is estimated to exceed quota, is executed?

I've read throgh [gcp's document on quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota) but this situation is not documented.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query can't be executed if it reach the quota limit. Let's say you have a quota to 10Gb per day per user

- If you perform a request of 6Gb, ok, it works
- If you perform another request of 6Gb, it fails
- If you perform a new request of 3Gb, it works.

Comment: Great, thank you! That's what I wanted to know. One more question: is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Not really clear. I tested it before answering you. You can check this page, but not clear: https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#quota_errors